# c# add program to windows startup (windows 7)

Tags: c#, window, registry

I'm trying to add my program to the windows start up programs by adding the program execution path to the registry editor.

This is the code:

```
RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);  
registryKey.SetValue("progExe", Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Surprisingly, when i restart the computer, the program does not run in the startup...

I can see the the program is the `msconfig` window ,with it's checkbox ticked.. but when i go that registry path,i can't find the key i used at all(`"progEXE")`...i made sure i'm searching in the right registry path...

[image]

[image]
Does anyone has any idea what could be the problem in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "but when i go that registry path" -- Do that again, then right click on the key and go to "Copy Key Name" and paste it in here. You are writing to `Registry.CurrentUser`, but I bet you are opening some "all users" registry key when viewing in regedit. E.g., `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` versus `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Comment: @Quantic i can't copy the key name..because i dont find it on the list...
p.s did you mean to this?
HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Comment: I mean on the left side, right click on "Run" and go to "Copy Key Name" and paste it in here. Also I edited that comment so read it again.

Comment: @Quantic look at the screenshot i added. you can see that's the correct path :(

Comment: Are you calling [`RegistryKey.Close`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.close(v=vs.110).aspx)? It looks like it won't actually write to the key until you call Close on it. I'm still confused as to how your program is showing up in msconfig which I think just enumerates a couple registry locations (one of them is the one you are looking at in the screenshot). edit: actually yes, msconfig shows "location" on the right, what's the location of your app when you see it in msconfig? I mean the registry location.

Comment: Also apparently all of my directions are backwards on your computer, heh. So the registry location in msconfig very well may be on the left and not the right.. [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/440344) image is what I'm seeing on my computer when I talk about "Location"; HKLM is "HKey Local Machine" and HKCU is "HKey Current User" in that screenshot.

Comment: @Quantic i uploaded a new screenshot.. you can see the path in the registry... i'll try to add the `Close()` part to see what's the real problem..

Comment: "i'll try to add the Close()" -- I don't think that's it, msconfig is clearly finding something in the registry location and displaying it to you. Look at the bottom of your regedit window in the screenshot, it says `HKCU\...\CurrentVersion\Run\{some characters I cant read}`, you apparently are viewing a subfolder under `Run`. Take another screenshot of regedit but make sure the path at the bottom ends on `...\Run` and has no other characters after it. My hunch is your program *is* running on startup, but is crashing or not showing UI for some reason--go to Event Viewer, look for app crash.

Comment: I would rather do this with Windows Task Scheduler, it has API calls as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off-topic: add a null check before trying to set the value, or write with a questionmark like so "registryKey?.SetValue(..."